# What are the conditions that cause a React Component to be controlled/uncontrolled? I have an example where it changes?

Tags: reactjs

So I'll just show you the code...it works when I call:

```
onChange={e => this.onTextChange('payment_amount', e, 'float')}/>
```

...when the `payment_amount` is directly on `this.state`...but when I call it nested...

```
onChange={e => this.onTextChange('outgoingPayment.payment_amount', e, 'float')}/>
```

...I get an error complaining about it going from controlled/uncontrolled and I don't understand what is doing it. I'll provide the involved functions below...they work in terms of assuming this props are residing on `this.state`...I had to flattened the `Payment` object into state in order to call the working version.

Actually I guess there is `runFunc()`...but it just returned an empty function is the one you passed isn't a function or undefined or something.

```
onTextChange(columnKey, e, numberKind = null, runAfter = null) {
  var self = this;
  var container = {};
  var value = e.target.value;
  if(columnKey.includes('.')) {
    container = getNestedProp(self.state, columnKey, -1);
    if(!container) return;
    var prop = getNestedPropName(self.state, columnKey);
    container[prop] = e.target.value;
    value = container;
    columnKey = getNestedPropName(self.state, columnKey, -1);
  }
  var finalValue = value;
  if(isGood(numberKind)) {
    switch(numberKind) {
      case 'float': finalValue = parseFloat(value); break;
      case 'integer': finalValue = parseInt(value); break;
    }
    // allow for backspace
    if(value === '') finalValue = '';
    // convert whatever is entered
    else if(isNaN(finalValue)) finalValue = 0;
  }
  console.log('finalValue', finalValue);
  self.setState({[columnKey]: finalValue}, () => runFunc(runAfter)());
}

function getNestedProp(container, propString, offset = 0) {
  if(offset > 0)
    alert('getNestedProp(): use negative numbers to offset from end');
  var props = propString.split('.');
  var _ref = container;
  for(var i = 0; i < props.length + offset; i++) {
    if(!_ref) throw('error: _ref is null or undefined');
    _ref = _ref[props[i]];
  }
  return _ref;
}

function getNestedPropName(container, propString, offset = 0) {
  if(offset > 0)
    alert('getNestedPropName(): use negative numbers to offset from end');
  var props = propString.split('.');
  var propName = '';
  var _ref = container;
  for(var i = 0; i < props.length + offset; i++) {
    if(!_ref) throw('error: _ref is null or undefined');
    propName = props[i];
    _ref = _ref[propName];
  }
  return propName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is when I go far enough that I end up asking a Stack question for something...when I look at what I've put together in the question...it comes to me 9 times out of 10...lolsigh.

The nested props version doesn't work for setting state as I have it...only if the flat prop is directly on state...needs to set be able to set the `container[prop] = value` then `setState({[container]: container})` before it'll work it seems.

Sorry if anyone wasted their time. Should I delete the question in this case or leave it for historical purposes?